# Laravel - check if a relationship exists

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm trying to check if a Model has a relationships using `with('')`

```
$currentUser = User::with('account.member.country', 'identity')->first();

$relations = collect($currentUser->getrelations())->values();  //or without converting
```

with `getrelations()` I can get the account and the identity relations

how I can make it dynamically and check if the account has also a relation (member) as long as a nested Relation exist  ?

I mean with nested relation in my example the member is a nested Relation from account and the country is nested from member.

Comment: Not quite clear what it is you want, but look into [`has` and `whereHas`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence).

Comment: sorry for my Bad english,I try to explain it more:

the main reason why I need it, that I need to check with ACL which privilige has user by each field of the model (all are saved as a json file, each table and each column and the privilige)
the was just an example with the User Model, but I need it a general function to check all nested relation by a Model. 

```$currentUser = User::with('account.member.country', 'identity'');```

with foreach I can get just the first main relations to the user account, identity but it is possible the the account has also a nested relation

Answer (score 0):

Check the relationship key has been set i.e.

`!empty($post->user_id)`

This way you avoid an unnecessary DB query. Obviously this would only work for belongsToRelationships.

For other relationship types, you can use the has method of the class i.e.

`Post::has('user')`

If you already have the model, you can do `$post->newQuery()->has('user');` or `$post->user()->exists()`.

So yeah, there are a lot of different options.

[See what the Laravel Documentation says](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if what you're looking for but you can use the exists helper method which will return a boolean if a relation exists,

```php
User::first()->has('dogs')->exists();
```

will return true if the first user has a relation with dogs.

Answer (score -2):

I found the Solution it's basiclly a Recursive function

```
protected  $relationNames = [];

function recursive($model){

        foreach($model as $key => $value){

           $this->relationNames[$key] =$value;

            if(count($value->getrelations()) > 0){

                $this->recursive($value->getrelations());
            }
        }
  }
```