# Laravel site can't be reached when adding an if statement in a model attribute

Tags: laravel

This is the first time I'm facing this issue, when adding an if statement in a model attribute and trying to load the page i get an error that the site can't be reached, although when removing the if statement the page loads perfectly, what could be the problem?

The problem occurs in the `getGeneratedNameAttribute`

Code Example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class orderPayment extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $appends = ['generatedName'];


    protected $guarded = [];

    public function order() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Order::class, 'order_id');
    }

    public function notes() {
        return $this->hasMany(Note::class, 'payment_id');
    }

    public function partPayments() {
        return $this->hasMany(PartPayment::class, 'payment_id');
    }

    public function getGeneratedNameAttribute() {

      
        if($this->order->retainer) {
            $monthName = Carbon::now()->day(1)->month($this->month)->translatedFormat('F');
            
            return 'Month '.$monthName.' '.$this->year;
        }
      
        return $this->name;
        

    }

}
```

Laravel Version: v10.12.0

Comment: if  `$this->order` is null then it may result in error so, you should add an additional conditon `if ($this->order && $this->order->retainer)`

Comment: It cannot be null, although that's a good notice, changing it still did not made it work. It does not display any errors, it displays the default page that the site cannot be reached.

Comment: try $appends = ['generated_name'] ``attribute names are typically referenced using their "snake case" serialized representation, even though the accessor's PHP method is defined using "camel case"`` also do ``$this->order?->retainer``

Comment: @Steve are you getting any error in laravel.log?

Comment: @discussion No errors are displaying in laravel.log

Comment: @Sumitkumar Already tried those, still same error

Comment: `->month($this->month)` expects an integer value

Comment: @krisgjika It is an integer value

Comment: Try to check if the relation exist with the exists() method.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60602838/laravel-check-if-a-relationship-exists
:)

Comment: @Steve provide the whole stack trace than

Answer (score -1):

1. Check if the $this->order relationship is defined correctly and if
   it returns the expected result. Make sure that the order_id foreign
   key in the order_payment table corresponds to the primary key of the
   Order model.
2. Verify that the retainer attribute exists in the Order model. If it
   doesn't exist or has a different name, it could cause an error when
   accessing $this->order->retainer.
3. Ensure that the order relationship is eager loaded when retrieving
   the orderPayment model. If it's not eager loaded, accessing
   $this->order could trigger additional queries, which may cause
   performance issues or errors.

   ```
   $orderPayment = OrderPayment::with('order')->find($id);
   ```

   Please ensure the above steps.

Comment: Already done all of the above steps, that's why i went ahead and posted this question. Because it is strange. I'm also able to see the value through tinker.

Comment: Consider wrapping the code inside a try-catch block to catch any potential exceptions and log the error message. This can help identify the specific issue causing the site to be unreachable.

Comment: Also did that, nothing happens.

Answer (score -1):

One possible issue is Order model is loading orderpayment/s relation on load, and the operation ends up with a continued loop.
Two possible scenarios that can cause the issue are:

1. You added orderpayment to $with array of Order model
2. one of get/set attribute name method of Order model is called "orderpayment.

Try the following code

```
public function getGeneratedNameAttribute(){ 
    if ($this->order_id){
        $order = Order::find($this->order, ['retainer']);
        if($order && $order->retainer){
            $month = Carbon::now()->month($this->month);
            $monthName = $month->translatedFormat('F');
            return 'Month ' . $monthName . ' ' . $this->year;
        }
    }
    return $this->name;
}
```

Please share Order model if the solution doesn't work